# "android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content" on showDialog(dialogId)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

This one is driving me to the brink of insanity!

I have an activity where I initialize a Button view with an onClickListener, like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

    mMyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);
    mMyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(ID_MYDIALOG);
        }
    });
}
```

I have also written my own dialog builder class (a singleton) since I have several other Activity's in my application which will be using a common set of dialogs, hence in the `onCreateDialog(int id)` function for the given Activity I call:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;

    switch (id) {
        case ID_MYDIALOG:
            dialog = DialogBuilder.getInstance().getMyDialog(this, mUri, mListener);
            break;

        default:
            dialog = null;
            break;
    }

    return dialog;
}
```

The `mUri` and `mListener` variables are defined elsewhere and I have verified that they are valid. The relevant parts of the singleton `DialogBuilder` class looks like this:

```
public AlertDialog getMyDialog(Context context, Uri uri, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
    // Inflate the custom body for the AlertDialog.
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.myDialogBody, null);

    // Get the data to show in the dialog.
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    // Create a suitable data adapter and use it to populate the dialog body with data.
    MyDialogDataAdapter adapter = new MyDialogDataAdapter(context, cursor);

    // Populate the GridView in the dialog body with data.
    GridView grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.myDialogDataGrid);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.myDialogIcon)
    .setTitle(R.string.myDialogTitle)
    .setView(view)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.myDialogDone, listener)
    .create();
}
```

Now, when I run my application and tap the button (i.e. `mMyButton`) I get the following exception stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:181)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:203)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:251)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:886)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2557)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2524)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at com.dbm.myApp.myActivity$4.onClick(myActivity.java:266)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2534)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9210)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3652)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1247):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  212):   Force finishing activity com.dbm.myApp/.myActivity
```

If I interpret the stack trace correctly the issue is triggered the very moment I tap my button (as of `com.dbm.myApp.myActivity$4.onClick(myActivity.java:266)` which is the exact `showDialog(ID_MYDIALOG);` line).

*What do you, fellow Android developers say? What du you think is causing my problem?*

It's fair to assume that the above code is valid, as per compilation and unit tests etc. The given code is, however, simplified and stripped to fit the forum, hence, please don't put an effort to comment the naming conventions etc.

Comment: I've come across this but I can't remember the exact fix :-( Do you need to call: `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);` In your DialogBuilder class?

Comment: A good tip, I just tested it, but unfortunately the issue remains. Also I might have to read up a bit on the requestFeature() function (or the short-cut version: requestWindowFeature()) and what they really do to my application.

Comment: I have now tested to comment out everything in the `getMyDialog` function in the singleton `DialogBuilder` class and the very same issue remains. I'm starting to think that my Activity isn't properly initialized.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think I might have solved the issue: If I for some reason create the AlertDialog with:

```
return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.myDialogIcon)
    .setTitle(R.string.myDialogTitle)
    .setView(view)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.myDialogDone, listener)
    .show();
```

I.e. with `.show();` instead of `.create();` The issue is no longer present. I don't know why this works or what differs the `AlertDialog.Builder::show()` function from the `AlertDialog.Builder::create();` function (more than the obvious difference reflected in respective function names).

Comment: Sorry for answering my own question. But I'm not sure how I otherwise could clearly and indisputably show that I solved my own problem.

Comment: Why the downvote? At least have the decency to leave a comment.

Comment: I found that dialog.findViewById, caused the mentioned exception to be thrown, if not using activity managed dialogs. I wrote about it in this almost identical question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826407/android-util-androidruntimeexception-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-ad

Comment: In my case I was using setContentView(view) and setButton() and had same problem API17 (min 10), solved by using setView(view) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try to call the `.setView(view)` right after constructor.

```
return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setView(view)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.myDialogIcon)
    .setTitle(R.string.myDialogTitle)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.myDialogDone, listener)
    .create();
```

Does it help?

Comment: I have now tested your suggestion as well. I have also tried to create my dialog first and assigning values to it once it's been instantiated, but that fails to.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the solution..but I was a bit suprised by this piece:

```
mMyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    showDialog(ID_MYDIALOG);
```

I thought you should implement *onClick* inside the listener? am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! You're perfectly correct in your comment. And in my live code it is written correctly as well (implementing the `onClick` function). I was a bit to eager to submit my question, though (sorry for that).

Comment: @dbm Answering your own question is welcomed, especially if no-one else has answered it correctly!