# How to switch alertDialog content?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-progressbar

### Background

I have an AlertDialog that is used in a DialogFragment, which I wish to switch in it between 3 states:

- a progress bar , which is centered in the screen, making everything else a bit darker.
- a ListView as the content, and a title.
- same as the first state.

I need to use the same dialog and not create a new one, yet be able to switch between those states.

### The problem

I can't manage to do it using the normal APIs.

### What I've tried

If I use "setView", it doesn't show anything except for making the screen darker.

If I use "setContentView", the listView takes the entire space, and it's also transparent vs the activity below (I know it's supposed to be transparent, but below a nice dialog) and looks weird . It's also without showing the title of the alertDialog.

### The question

How can I solve this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy. You can have a FrameLayout view the holds the views for your 3 states. Show or hide them as needed.

For an example how to derive an AlertDialog to have a custom content view look here: [example](https://github.com/czeidler/Lablet/blob/master/app/src/main/java/nz/ac/auckland/lablet/camera/FrameRateSettingsDialog.java) Here I just rebuild the whole view.

Comment: The "setContentView" is not a part of the AlertDialog. It's for Dialog (I know, the functions names are very confusing and don't make sense) : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setContentView(android.view.View) . It uses the entire space on the screen. I want that for some states (first and third in the list of states) it won't be shown like an AlertDialog at all. Just a progress bar on a dialog (making the rest of the screen dimmed).

Comment: About the example, can you please explain what does "addContentView" help here, and how to switch between the states (I don't see anything there that allows to switch between them) ?

Comment: You have to do the state switching on your own. The addContentView just adds the container FrameLayout that holds your three states. When an event occurs that makes the state switching necessary you call newStateView.setVisibility(VISIBLE) and oldStateView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE).

Comment: Have you tried it? for me it causes an exception (when using "addContentView" inside the "onCreateDialog" method, right after creating the dialog) : "android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content"

Comment: Yes the example I gave is working for me. Are you requesting a window feature for the dialog? I don't call the parent onCreate method, maybe its that? or are you using the Builder? Please post your code if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I don't call onCreate and I don't call onCreateDialog. It's being called by itself since it's a DialogFragment. I don't request any window feature. I use the AlertDialog.Builder to create the AlertDialog.

Comment: Have you tried: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826407/android-util-androidruntimeexception-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-ad)

Comment: I don't understand which part there you are talking about. when I get back home, I will try to post a short snippet of a POC for this question.